# Парсинг CSV файла с расписанием

Tags: python, парсер, pandas, dataframe, csv

Есть CSV файл, в котором в строку указано расписание работы некоторых "предприятий".

В формате:

```
Kushi Tsuru,"Mon-Sun 11:30 am - 9 pm"
Osakaya Restaurant,"Mon-Thu, Sun 11:30 am - 9 pm  / Fri-Sat 11:30 am - 9:30 pm"
The Stinking Rose,"Mon-Thu, Sun 11:30 am - 10 pm  / Fri-Sat 11:30 am - 11 pm"
McCormick & Kuleto's,"Mon-Thu, Sun 11:30 am - 10 pm  / Fri-Sat 11:30 am - 11 pm"
Mifune Restaurant,"Mon-Sun 11 am - 10 pm"
The Cheesecake Factory,"Mon-Thu 11 am - 11 pm  / Fri-Sat 11 am - 12:30 am  / Sun 10 am - 11 pm"
New Delhi Indian Restaurant,"Mon-Sat 11:30 am - 10 pm  / Sun 5:30 pm - 10 pm"
Iroha Restaurant,"Mon-Thu, Sun 11:30 am - 9:30 pm  / Fri-Sat 11:30 am - 10 pm"
```

Необходимо сделать программу, которая будет по запросу даты, например:
`Jan 01 2018 12:00AM` или `Feb 02 2019 11:50PM`
выводить, какие "предприятия" работали в данный день и данное время.

Например, User вводит дату (*Feb 02 2019 11:50PM*). Программа выводит лишь те "предприятия", что согласно файлу (расписанию) работают в тот день.

Kак это можно реализовать?

Comment: А что конкретно непонятно? Как с файла считывать? Или как парсить строки из файла? Или как даты из строки конвертировать в дату-объект? Или как делать сравнение дат?

Comment: @gil9red User вводит дату и время, а в расписании даны лишь промежутки времени.
Не понятно, каким образом можно подставить вводимую дату, получить из неё день недели и сверить её с расписанием. Никогда такого не делал.

Comment: @AlexandrS, вы можете привести в вопросе неюольшие примеры входных и выходных данных?

Comment: @MaxU конечно ......

Comment: мда, вот такие диапазоны: `11 am - 12:30 am`  (`11:00 - 00:30`) очень трудно будет обрабатывать

Comment: Самое сложное в этом вопросе -- парсинг даты. Придется замудриться с парсером. @AlexandrS, ` / ` разделяются даты, а `Fri-Sat` показываются диапазон дня недели, а `11 am - 12:30 am` диапазон времени в сутках?

Comment: @gil9red, с этим можно справиться... а вот как быть с диапазоном времени для определенных дней недели, но когда этот диапазон "вываливается" из текущего дня?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Мне данная задача показалось достаточно интересной, чтобы потратить на нее некоторое время.

решение:

```
import re
import time
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime as DT

#библиотека функций для парсинга:

def tm_to_min(t, fmt='%H:%M %p'):
    try:
        t = time.strptime(t, '%I %p')
    except ValueError:
        t = time.strptime(t, '%I:%M %p')
    # return # of minutes from the midnight
    return t.tm_hour*60 + t.tm_min

def parse_time_range(s):
    tm_from, tm_to = re.findall(r'(\d{1,2}\:?\d*?\s+[ap]m)', s)
    return tm_to_min(tm_from), tm_to_min(tm_to)

def range_to_csv(s):
    if re.match('\d$', s):
        return s
    m = re.search(r'(\d)\s*-\s*(\d)', s)
    if m:
        a,b = map(int, m.groups())
        return ''.join(map(str, (range(a, b+1))))
    else:
        return ''

def range_to_list(s):
    if re.match('\d$', s):
        return [int(s)]
    m = re.search(r'(\d)\s*-\s*(\d)', s)
    if m:
        a,b = map(int, m.groups())
        return list(range(a, b+1))
    else:
        return []


def get_weekdays(s):
    # cut off a time range
    s = re.sub(r'\s+\d.*$', '', s)
    s = (s.replace('Mon', '1')
          .replace('Tue', '2')
          .replace('Wed', '3')
          .replace('Thu', '4')
          .replace('Fri', '5')
          .replace('Sat', '6')
          .replace('Sun', '7')
        )
    ret = ''
    for x in re.split('\s*,\s*', s):
        #ret += range_to_list(x)
        ret += range_to_csv(x)
    return ret

def parse_sched(s):
    weekdays = get_weekdays(s)
    m_from, m_to = parse_time_range(s)
    return pd.Series([weekdays, m_from, m_to])

def dt_to_sched(s):
    d = pd.to_datetime(s)
    w = str(d.week+1)
    minutes = d.hour * 60 + d.minute
    return w,minutes

def create_schedule(df):
    # функция "explode()" отсюда: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40449726/5741205
    t = explode(df.assign(sched=df.sched.str.split('\s*/\s*')), 'sched')
    t[['weekdays','min_from','min_to']] = t.sched.apply(parse_sched)
    # replace time ranges like "11 am - 12:30 am"  --> "11:00 - 23:59:59"
    t.loc[t.min_to < t.min_from, 'min_to'] = 24*60
    return t
#############################################

# парсим CSV
df = pd.read_csv(r'C:\download\schedule.csv', header=None, names=['name', 'sched'])
# создаем расписание в виде нормализованного DF
t = create_schedule(df)

# имитируем ввод даты пользователем
user_date = 'Feb 02 2019 9PM'
w, mins = dt_to_sched(user_date)

# проверка расписания    
res = t.loc[t.weekdays.str.contains(w) & (mins >= t.min_from) & (mins <= t.min_to), 'name'].drop_duplicates()
```

результат:

```
In [394]: res
Out[394]:
0                     Kushi Tsuru
2              Osakaya Restaurant
4               The Stinking Rose
6            McCormick & Kuleto's
7               Mifune Restaurant
9          The Cheesecake Factory
11    New Delhi Indian Restaurant
14               Iroha Restaurant
Name: name, dtype: object
```

как выглядит DataFrame `t` с расписанием:

```
In [395]: t
Out[395]:
                           name                            sched weekdays  min_from  min_to
0                   Kushi Tsuru          Mon-Sun 11:30 am - 9 pm  1234567       690    1260
1            Osakaya Restaurant     Mon-Thu, Sun 11:30 am - 9 pm    12347       690    1260
2            Osakaya Restaurant       Fri-Sat 11:30 am - 9:30 pm       56       690    1290
3             The Stinking Rose    Mon-Thu, Sun 11:30 am - 10 pm    12347       690    1320
4             The Stinking Rose         Fri-Sat 11:30 am - 11 pm       56       690    1380
5          McCormick & Kuleto's    Mon-Thu, Sun 11:30 am - 10 pm    12347       690    1320
6          McCormick & Kuleto's         Fri-Sat 11:30 am - 11 pm       56       690    1380
7             Mifune Restaurant            Mon-Sun 11 am - 10 pm  1234567       660    1320
8        The Cheesecake Factory            Mon-Thu 11 am - 11 pm     1234       660    1380
9        The Cheesecake Factory         Fri-Sat 11 am - 12:30 am       56       660    1440 # <-- время после полуночи игнорируется
10       The Cheesecake Factory                Sun 10 am - 11 pm        7       600    1380
11  New Delhi Indian Restaurant         Mon-Sat 11:30 am - 10 pm   123456       690    1320
12  New Delhi Indian Restaurant              Sun 5:30 pm - 10 pm        7      1050    1320
13             Iroha Restaurant  Mon-Thu, Sun 11:30 am - 9:30 pm    12347       690    1290
14             Iroha Restaurant         Fri-Sat 11:30 am - 10 pm       56       690    1320
```

Comment: Здравствуйте!...........Извините за долгий ответ. Не смог разобраться сразу, сейчас вернулся к этому проекту......................................................................... Выпадает ошибка: "NameError: name 'explode' is not defined"............................................. Такой переменной действительно НЕТ. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как локализовать эту проблему?

Comment: @AlexandrS, комментарии в коде внимательней читайте ;)

Comment: Окей)))))))))))))

Answer (score 0):

1). Парсите ваши строчки, чтобы вытащить из кождой четыре значения: день недели начала рабочей недели, день недели завершения рабочей недели, время начала работы, время окончания работы. Эта часть тривиальна. Дни недели лучше приводить к их номерам в интовом типе.

2). Когда пользователь вводит дату/время:

2.1). Получаете день недели. Например с помощью метода .isoweekday()

2.2). Проверяете, что он не меньше дня начала рабочей недели

2.3). Проверяете, что он не больше дня окончания рабочей недели

2.4). Выделяете только время и проверяете, что оно не меньше времени начала работы и не больше времени окончания работы.

Если все проверки проходят - предприятие работает в этот момент времени.

Comment: Можете привести пример, пожалуйста ...

Comment: Пример чего? Какой именно пункт непонятен? Задавайте вопросы конкретнее.

Comment: Прошу прощение .... Пункт номер 1.Никогда ранее не занимался парсингом. Например: 

Osakaya Restaurant,"Mon-Thu, Sun 11:30 am - 9 pm  / Fri-Sat 11:30 am - 9:30 pm"

Comment: Здесь структура сильно сложнее, чем в той строчке, которую вы привели в вопросе. Добавьте в вопрос десяток разных строчек, я посмотрю.

Comment: Добавил, посмотрите, пожалуйста.